# How to generate Automatically resx files for project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, resx, auto-generate

I want to generation automatically Resx files for my project,  I've heared that there's program which does it.
Can anyone tell me it's name?

Answer (score 4):

The only program I know is Visual Studio.  You can easily create your own program by using the ResXResourceWriter class.

Comment: Let's see, I have a form, with labels, buttons etc. with French text meanings. I Have a resx file, where is all this information.. now I want to translate this meanings to English. I need resx file with all those strings. That's why I need program to generate automatic resx depending on first one. If there is other solution of that, if I can write something in my source and it will do that please tell me.

Comment: Windows Forms already has *great* support for that.  Set the Localizable property of the form to True, change the Language property.  This automatically generates the .resx files and the satellite assemblies.

Comment: @Hans, If I wanted to outsource the translation, but didn't want to give users access to the sourse code (they don't want or have visual studio anyway), what is the easiest way to get these translations and (and change the sizes of controls), links would be useful. thanks.

Comment: @Mr - all they need is the .resx files.

Comment: Unfortuantly all the translation companies we approached don't want, or understand the .resx files, the simply want a list or document to translate.

Answer (score 2):

As Hans stated, for components such as forms and user controls, you can do this via the "Localizable" property. For other ".resx" files, you can easily create your own localized ".resx" file but it needs to be properly named (you can read up on this - Google for "satellite assemblies" for starters). If your goal is dealing with translations in general however, then unless your app is very small, this approach is difficult, tedious and error-prone (trying to track changed strings on your own for instance, whose existing translations have become obsolete). There are 3rd-party packages that can help you however, and I'm the author of one of them (in the interest of full disclosure). See http://www.hexadigm.com.

Comment: +1 for the `Localizable` property and the "satellite assemblies"